# Can host be extracted from referer in mod_rewrite for htaccess / apache?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, .htaccess

I'm trying to do a rewrite where I need the host part of the HTTP_REFERER.

So if the referer is e.g. *http://www.example.com/some/path* I need to extract the host part, *www.example.com* and use it in the RewriteRule, so that it rewrites to */some/serverpath/www.example.com/subfolder*.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^/:]+)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/some/serverpath/
RewriteRule ^ /some/serverpath/%1/subfolder
```